# Delete whitespace in Visual Studio Code in arbitrary selection (aka join words) (not trim trailing whitespace)

Tags: visual-studio-code

It seems like this should be a simple question, but I can't figure out how to delete all the whitespace within an arbitrary selection in Visual Studio Code (another way of saying this is to join all characters within a selection).

Note: I'm not asking how to trim trailing whitespace although this function could be used to manually to that.

It seems like there should be a built in way to do this, but if there isn't can someone point me to an extension that will do this?

I wasn't able to find one yet.

Comment: Not a duplicate.. this is inside of any arbitrary selection, not just trailing spaces

Comment: One potential idea (that I haven't tried) is to setup a macro with a keyboard shortcut that does a find/replace on the selection using regex. https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=geddski.macros

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here's an extension (remove-whitespace-aka-join-words) I built to do just this:

https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=tnrich.remove-whitespace-aka-join-words

Answer (score 8):

You can do it fairly easily without an extension.

- Copy the selection
- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>N</kbd> (opens new unnamed blank document)
- Paste
- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>H</kbd> (replace dialog), space, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>Enter</kbd> (replace-all)

Now copy the update string to where you want it, and close the document.

Answer (score 3):

Just adding this here for 2022. I use one of these two methods. The first I don't have to remember the Regular Expression formula:
**Method 1:**
Sometimes this method will strip all spaces in your code (which isn't intended). If that occurs, try the next method. I often try this method first.

- Select an empty space, and push `CTRL + F`, or `Apple key + F` on mac. This will highlight all matching characters, spaces.
- Push the `Replace All` button to replace them all with nothing.
- Hit `CTRL + SHIFT + P' or` Apple key + Shift + P', and select `Format Document`.

**Method 2:**
Found here: https://www.trainingdragon.co.uk/blog/how-to-remove-empty-lines-in-visual-studio-code/

- Push `CTRL + F`, or `Apple key + F` on mac. Select the `Use Regular Expression` button, or push `Apple key + option + R` to toggle it on/off.
- Add `^(\s)*$\n` to the find input box.
- Push the `Replace All` button to replace them all.

Answer (score 2):

Depending on your selection you might be able by simply

1. Select the first space
2. <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd> to select the next space, and repeat for all your spaces
3. <kbd>Delete</kbd>

---

Here is a technique that could be of more general use.  Make a keybinding like so:

```
  {
    "key": "shift+alt+y",            // or whatever keybinding you want
    "command":  "editor.action.insertSnippet",
    "args": {
      "snippet": "${TM_SELECTED_TEXT/\\s//g}"  // replace spaces with nothing
    },
    "when": "editorTextFocus && editorHasSelection"
  },
```

Then select your text and trigger this command.  [Or make it a snippet and trigger it through the command palette `Insert Snippet` command.]

This could be modified to use for many things very easily - in part because often the regex will be quite simple as it will operate within already selected text.

---

You can also just do a Find/Replace easily:

1. Find:    just a space
2. Replace: with nothing
3. Make your selection
4. Enable the `Find in Selection` option - the "hamburger-like icon" to the right

Answer (score 0):

downloaded this beautiful extension in VS Code https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=bhughes339.replacerules

added to settings.json:

```
"replacerules.rules": {
        "joinWords0": {
            "find": "\\s",
            "replace": "",
        }
    },    
    "replacerules.rulesets": {
        "ruleset0": {
            "rules": [
                "joinWords0"
            ]
        }
    }
```

added to 'keybindings.json':

```
{
        "key": "ctrl+shift+alt+n",
        "command": "replacerules.runRule",
        "when": "editorTextFocus",
        "args": {
            "ruleName": "joinWords0"
        }
    }
```

now I'm able to with 1. selecting text I want to join and 2. pressing a simple "ctrl+shift+alt+n" delete whitespace in Visual Studio Code in arbitrary selection (aka join words)!!